# I can't setup VAT for german shop in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

I setup a Tax Class * with 19%, the I add a product with the price 32.77, this price is without VAT
[image]

after this I setup the tax in System > Configuration > Sales > Tax like this:

[image]

My problem is that i have this warning and the Catalog Product Prices is still 32.77, when VAT is added the price in catalog must be 39. And the same in the checkout page the VAT is not calculated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you have catalog prices entered including tax**

[image]

**so you have your final price here**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating price based on billing address and add tax to shipping also. This should work.

Comment: Please don't provide one line answers add some code or some more explanation.